# Inserting Collections to Models with jQuery and ASP.NET MVC, creating plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

After looking at the available options, I'm looking at making a plugin for jQuery (and coincidentally, a library for ASP.NET MVC) that will provide some simple methods for dynamically adding objects to a collection of a ViewModel.

I speak of things like this ( http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/640_Adding_Multiple_Nested_Data_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Application.aspx )

I was wondering if there is already anything out there like that, though, before I start building one of my own.

Comment: Sounds like [this] might be exactly what you are looking for. [this]: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny Chao nods to Steve Sanderson without mentioning the very interesting [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/).

It is more a framework, but works perfectly well with jquery and the upcoming jquery templates for that matter.

In particular: for adding objects to a collection you would want to look closely at the [observableArrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Not surprising for a writer of [asp.net-mvc books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865), Steve provides an mvc [sample](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) and there is an [active forum](http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs) with many from .net backgrounds, though it is not strictly a .net framework.